# d3 v4 - can't scroll vertically on svg containing bar chart

Tags: d3.js

**EDIT - added a code snippet (bottom)**

The amount of rows are dynamic, so I don't know what the total height needed is. I have initiated the height as 800px, but the list can grow longer. I have a container div with an `overflow-y:scroll` value, but that did not solve the issue. D3 code and css below.

1. There is a scroll bar, but if I scroll down no more rows show.
2. The chart itself only measures about 644px (in Photoshop), so I'm not sure why it is cutting off where it does, or if that is a separate issue.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let randProb = () => {
      let min = 0;
      let max = 1;
      return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(4)
    };
    
    var data = [];
    
    let initData = () => {      
      for (let i=0; i<86; ++i) {
        data.push({
          "attribute":`ATTRIBUTE_${i}`, 
          "probabilityOfMastery":randProb()
        });
      }
//      console.log('data initialized', data);
    };
    

    initData();
    
    
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 0, right: 20, bottom: 0, left: 160},
    width = 1220 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    // set the ranges
    var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 0])
    .padding(0.1);
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // append a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select(".analyticsContainer").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    // format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.probabilityOfMastery = +d.probabilityOfMastery;
    });
    // Scale the range of the data in the domains
    x.domain([0, 1])
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.attribute; }));
    //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.probabilityOfMastery; })]);
    // append the rectangles for the bar chart
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")    
    .attr("width", 0 )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.attribute); })
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    //- .delay(function(d, i) {
    //-   return i * 60
    //- })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.probabilityOfMastery); } )
    ;
    // add the x Axis
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    // add the y Axis
    svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
});
```

```css
.analyticsWrapper {
  height:calc(100vh - 120px);
  max-height:100%;
  width:100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border:1px solid red
}
 
.analyticsContainer {
    font-size: 40px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding:3.5vw;
    height:800px;
}

svg {
      width:90vw;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
}

.bar {
  fill: #11b9b9;
}

.yAxis text {
   font-weight: 700;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="analyticsWrapper">
   <div class="analyticsContainer">
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Since you have the JS and the CSS, why dont you add your HTML and create a **running code** for us? It's the button `<>` in the top panel.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - thanks Gerardo, I've never used that feature before, will make sure to do so going forward. Code snippet added.

Comment: @RonI Have you figured it out